# C# Creating implicit conversions for delagate type

Tags: c#, generics

Within our existing codebase, we have a delegate defined as anything that takes in a CancellationTolken and returns a task

```
public delegate Task CancelTask(CancellationToken ct);
```

There is also an equivalent for return type of `Task<T>`

We have run into a problem with a series of functions take these in and manipulate them. Most of the time, the functions are agnostic to the return type of the task. There is a huge amount of code duplication in order to make all of the functions complete for taking in any permutation of `CancelTask<T>` vs `CancelTask`

Is there anyway to (within a specific scope) allow for implicit conversion from the generic form to the non generic one? It seems that `Task<T>` can be used as a `Task` via inheritance, but I cant find any way to do this with these types (the type the delegate creates is sealed)

Things Ive tried so far:

- Writing implicit operator, cant be done as I cant modify type created by the delegate
- Creating class to act as inbetween, which could convert both types. Not sure how to finish this, as I cant find a way to convert a generic type to a non generic

Edit 1: Here is an example of what we want to do:

```
public static CancelTask<CancelTask<B>> Case<A, B>(
        CancelTask<A> cancelTask,
        Func<A, CancelTask<B>> continuation) => cancelTask.Select(continuation);

public static CancelTask<CancelTask> Case<A>(
        CancelTask<A> cancelTask,
        Func<A, CancelTask> continuation) => cancelTask.Select(continuation);

public static CancelTask<CancelTask> Case(
        CancelTask cancelTask,
        Func<CancelTask> continuation) => cancelTask.Select(continuation);
```

Select is a function that takes the return of the first cancelTask and feeds it to the continuation when the first is finished. We have so many overloads for this case method to handle every permutation of inputs, outputs, and intermediate results (the ones passed to the continuation). Adding functionality is painful because we need to make another n methods every time we add something for completeness.

Ideally, Im looking for a way to have a generalized base function, and do implicit casts of the inputs so that all the permutations can be cast to something usable. Example, if the third function is called with a CancelTask as the first parameter, it would be nice to downcast that to a CancelTask (we dont care about the output, only the flow control)

Comment: Could you please clarify "`Task<T>` can implicitly be used as a Task" remark? It sounds like you expect there to be some extra code beyond `Task<T>` being a `Task`... Consider to [edit] the question with that clarification.

Comment: Didnt realize that `Task<T>` inherited from `Task`, I thought there was an implicit conversion. I changed the question to reflect this

Comment: You could make all functions operate on `Task<T>` only, and rewrite the entry points for `Task` (and only those) to pass a `Task<Unit>` (`internal struct Unit {}`). This would reduce the code duplication to just the public part of the interfaces. In the rare case where it matters that the task doesn't have a result you could explicitly type check for `Task<Unit>`.

Comment: The `<T>` means you are not actually "Typeless". You would use `Type<T>` if you are returning arguments to/from your thread. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1?view=net-6.0

Comment: @Jeroen The functions we have cant operate on Task<T>, what we are actually passing around is equivalent to a `Func<CancellationTolken, T>`

Comment: @tgolisch In some contexts we care about the <T>, but other times we only want to know when the resulting task has ended so that we can do something else. For those transformations, the actual return value is unneeded

Comment: I have to admit I'm still not clear on your scenario, more code would probably help. What I do know is that you cannot define conversions on delegates, you have to settle for what implicit conversions allow. Going from one type to another is easy (`CancelTask<T> cType; CancelTask c = (CancellationToken ct) => cType(ct);`) but necessarily involves creating a new delegate, and cannot be done through an implicit conversion.